# Auto increment a SESSION key ID

Tags: php

I'm having a problem in doing something.
I have this code snippet to add a product to cart:

```
$product_id = isset($_GET['product_id']) ? $_GET['product_id'] : "";
$product_name = isset($_GET['product_name']) ? $_GET['product_name'] : "";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id LIKE '{$product_id}' AND product_name LIKE '{$product_name}' LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num == 1)
{
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
        {
            $product_id_session = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $count = count($_SESSION['cart']); 
            $product_id_session = $count++;
        }

        $columns = array
        (
            'product_id_session' => $product_id_session,
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'product_name' => $product_name,
            'product_price' => $product_price           
        );
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id_session] = $columns;      
        redirect_to('products.php?&message=added&product_name='. $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id_session]['product_name']);
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the session `cart` is created, I assign the variable `$product_id_session` with the count of SESSION arrays plus one. Otherwise, the variable `$product_id_session` is set to `1`. In the cart page I have a link to remove the selected product:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product)
{
    echo "<button onClick=\"location.href='remove.php?product_id_session={$product['product_id_session']}'\">
    Remove from cart
    </button>";
}
```

Then, in the **remove.php** file I have this to process the data from Query String and remove the product from the cart:

```
$product_id_session = isset($_GET['product_id_session']) ? $_GET['product_id_session'] : "";
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id_session]);
```

The problem I'm facing is: for example, I added two products in the cart. Then I removed the first product and added another product to the cart. The new product, instead of being added, just will replace the product that was previously added in the cart and the `$product_id_session` will be always the same value. What I'm doing wrong? How to specify an ID for the SESSION?

Comment: Not much point in preparing your statement if you are going to inject the user-supplied values directly in the query just the same: You have an sql injection problem.

Comment: @jeroen I only insert the values if they match in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new items to the cart just with:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $columns;
```

Then it will be appended to end of the array.

And, after deleting item from the array, you can (but it is not necessary) re-index it by

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array_values($_SESSION['cart']);
```

When printing out the cart, you just update the foreach loop to catch the key value into some variable, i.e. $index. The difference is in the $index=>$product part.

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $index=>$product)
{
    echo "<button onClick=\"location.href='remove.php?product_id_session={$index}'\">
    Remove from cart
    </button>";
}
```

Remove.php remains basically the same, I just updated it for better readibility:

```
if (isset($_GET['product_id_session']) and $_GET['product_id_session']) {
    $product_id_session = $_GET['product_id_session'];
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id_session]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to use `$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id_session]` because I will need to specify which product ID to remove and unset the respective SESSION array in the ***remove.php*** file.

Comment: I understand that. Still I don't think you need to keep $product_id_session in separate field - the value is already stored as index (key) of the value in array, you don't need to duplicate that number in $product_id_session. Try using `foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id_session=>$product)` in **remove.php** and you'll get that result as well.

Comment: But without this how I will unset the respective SESSION array?

Comment: You do it in the exact some way as before. I updated the answer so that there is an example of what I meant.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for taking your time to help me! A great hug, friend! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create an extra ID to manage your cart you should just rely on the unique product ID already stored in your database :

```
if($num == 1) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // no need for the loop as you only have 1 result
    extract($row);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    }
    // keep track of the added product for the time being
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id])) {
        $columns = array(
            'product_id_session' => $product_id_session,
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'product_name' => $product_name,
            'product_price' => $product_price,
            'amount' => 0, //just add last comma as good practise here
        );
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = $columns;
    }
    //raise the amount
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['amount']++;
    redirect_to('products.php?&message=added&product_name='. $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id_session]['product_name']);
}
```

And change the remove accordingly :

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) {
    echo "<button onClick=\"location.href='remove.php?product_id={$product['product_id']}'\">Remove from cart</button>";
}
```

EDIT :

To keep an "unique" id you should not use `count` to calculate the ID
Just use an extra variable to keep track of last Id :

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        $_SERVER['cart_product_id'] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SERVER['cart_product_id']++;
        $product_id_session = $_SERVER['cart_product_id'];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm doing an online ordering system, so the user can add the same product multiple times because I have a system of additions. I need to do this by specifying an ID for that SESSION array.

Comment: That is why i've added the `amount` in the array as well, to keep track of multipe orders of the same product

Comment: I can't assign the `product_id` as the ID to remove the product because I can have multiple products in the cart page with the same ID.

Comment: You will need to provide a bit more information on the products then, an ID should be something unique. Perhaps update your answer with a screenshot of the products.

Comment: To be honest, I do not need to add the product ID in the array. I just use the product ID to get the right product from database and set the price of it. I can have multiple products with the same name and ID in the cart page. What I need is to auto increment the `product_id_session`. With this, I can manage the right SESSION array after, acording to `product_id_session`, not the product id.